RegEx to capture specific instance of specific character
I have the following string:
[url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gk8ftgR9jK]Final digit was removed[/url]

I wish to replace the "]" char immediately following the YouTube v= string with a ">", but can't quite get the regex correct.
I am only able to select the complete string up to the FINAL "]", which is not what is required.
atag.replace(/https:\/\/.*?\]/, etc) //Haven't worked out the grouping yet, so "etc"


You could capture the part right before matching the ] in group 1 and then match ] after it. In the replacement use group 1 to keep that part and add the character > after it.
(https:\/\/[^\][]*)]

Regex demo
For example:


const atag = "[url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gk8ftgR9jK]Final digit was removed[/url]";
const result = atag.replace(/(https:\/\/[^\][]*)]/, "$1>");
console.log(result);



Or a bit  more specific and keeping the closing ] for the tag:
\[url=https:\/\/[^\][]*]

Regex demo


const atag = "[url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gk8ftgR9jK]Final digit was removed[/url]";
const result = atag.replace(/\[url=https:\/\/[^\][]*]/, "$&>");
console.log(result);




You could match and replace on the first [...]:


var url = "[url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gk8ftgR9jK]Final digit was removed[/url]";
var output = url.replace(/^\[(.*?)\]/, "[$1>");
console.log(output);



Or another slightly different version:


var url = "[url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gk8ftgR9jK]Final digit was removed[/url]";
var output = url.replace(/(.*?)\]/, "$1>");
console.log(output);




You can also use ^(\[url=https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube[^\r\n\]]+v=[a-z0-9]{10})\]([^\r\n\[]+\[\/url\])$ and replace it with $1>$2:


const regex =
  /^(\[url=https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube[^\r\n\]]+v=[a-z0-9]{10})\]([^\r\n\[]+\[\/url\])$/gi;

const str =
  "[url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gk8ftgR9jK]Final digit was removed[/url]";
console.log(str.replace(regex, `$1>$2`));




Note:
This pattern has many restrictions that you might wanna use:

^ is a start anchor.
(\[url=https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube[^\r\n\]]+v=[a-z0-9]{10}) is the capture group $1.

\[url=https?:\/\/ validates http or https.
(?:www\.)? optionally allows www..
youtube only allows youtube.
v=[a-z0-9]{10} checks for v followed by 10 alphanumeric chars.



-\]: ignores the bracket you want to replace.

([^\r\n\[]+\[\/url\]) is the second capture group.
$ is an end anchor.


You can use a positive lookbehind here to ensure that you're targeting the right character. This regex matches a ] character, but only when it's preceded by v= and then a string of letters and numbers (\w).
Using a positive lookbehind ((?<=)) allows you to make sure those characters are there without needing to match/capture/replace them


var url = "[url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gk8ftgR9jK]Final digit was removed[/url]";
var output = url.replace(/(?<=v=\w+)\]/, ">");
console.log(output);



